# How to execute cmds using HTTP Post method in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, api, rest, cypress

We have a REST endpoint installed as a windows service on a server. This server will be used for test automation. The idea is make a POST request to the endpoint and that endpoint will kick off cypress tests based off the parameters specified in the POST url.

I have an existing powershell script that will do this. Ideally I'd like to call that script and fill in the needed params.

No matter what I do the request returns OK without actually running any of the commands. Is there a way to use a POST request to execute a cmds or a powershell script?? Code below(Note: I'm trying 2 different methods here neither work):

```
namespace CNet.TestRunner
{
    public class AddTestRun : CNetApiEndpoint
    {
        [HttpPost("Cypress/{testName}/{serverName}")]
        public CineNetResult TestRun(string testName, string serverName)
        {
            string test = testName + ".js";

            string testPath = $@"..\EndToEndSpecs\cypress\integration\{test}";

            var path = "%PROGRAMFILES%";
            var resolvedPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
            string cmd = $@"{resolvedPath}\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe "" '..\EndToEnd.ps1' '-TestPath {testPath}' '-HostToTest {serverName}' """;


            Process P = Process.Start($@"{resolvedPath}\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe", $@""" '..\EndToEnd.ps1' '-TestPath {testPath}' '-HostToTest {serverName}'""");
            P.WaitForExit();
            int result = P.ExitCode;
            string resStr = result.ToString();
            
            var model = new ResponseModel
            {
                Message = resStr,
                DataPassed = $"{testName}|{serverName}"
            };
            var proc1 = new ProcessStartInfo();
            string anyCommand = "yarn install";
            proc1.UseShellExecute = true;

            proc1.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";

            proc1.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
            proc1.Verb = "runas";
            proc1.Arguments = "/c " + anyCommand;
            proc1.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(proc1);

            return Ok(model);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the user IIS runs as have permission to execute programs? Any exceptions? What debugging has been done so far? Execute ok in a dev env?

Comment: Yeah the user has permissions, I've tried putting the return in an if statement so that it will not return unless the commands are run and they return true. And confirmed the command is being built correctly. Nothing has worked